# Setting up new gate connections in initialize()

Tags: omnet++

I wish to increase the size of my gate vector within `initialize()` in my simple module class file and make a connection to another node.

```
cModule *nodeA= getSimulation()->getModule(0);
cModule *nodeB= getSimulation()->getModule(1);
nodeA->gate("port$o")->connectTo(nodeB->gate("port$i"));
```

The gate vectors for `nodeA` and `nodeB` are already full, i.e. all gates of the gate vectors have been assigned. Within a NED file in the connections section, I would be able to write something like the following:

```
nodeA.port++ --> ned.IdealChannel --> nodeB.port++;
```

This allows me to expand the size of the gate vectors and make a connection between the nodes. Is it possible to do something similar in C++?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the size of a gate vectors cannot be controlled using C++.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation. I ended up simply defining a large-enough gate vector in the NED file.